# Multisite - getting a 404 for additional site created using subdomain install

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I created an additional site on my multisite subdomain installation. Now when I try to visit the new site or its wp-admin, I get a 404 error.

My wordpress instance is hosted on AWS

Checked the following

- AllowOverride is set to All in
  httpd.conf
- contents of .htaccess are
  the same as those in Network settings
- added the necessary statements to
  wp-config.php
- Tried restarting httpd
  as well

What else could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a wildcard serveralias in that site's virtualhost declaration. Right under where it says `ServerName example.com` you should add another line like this:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

You might have already done that, but it was the only thing missing from the list of things you had checked.

Comment: No. I haven't added it. I don't see a <VirtualHost> tag in my httpd.conf. There isn't even a ServerName but I added it. When I add ServerAlias beneath it, it gives an error - ServerAlias only used in <VirtualHost>

Comment: So how do I add the ServerAlias? And will it cause any issues if I add a VirtualHost tag to my httpd.conf? When is it used?

Comment: What are the specs on your server (OS, version of Apache, etc)?

Comment: Generally, those things won't be in your httpd.conf file. They're usually in their own files so that they can be enabled and disabled. On my server (Ubuntu 11.04), the virtualhost files are in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Comment: Hosted on AWS - Apache version 2.2.16 (Unix server)

Comment: there is no such folder on the server. any idea how/where i can specify the virtualhost/server alias?

Comment: That worked for me.  I wonder what is required if you add a new domain entirely and point it to that server? Another apache record??